# Find implicit conversions

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm searching a way to find implicit conversion. Something which give me the packages where a conversion from one to the other type is.

As an example:

```
found   : java.lang.String("")
required: net.liftweb.http.js.JsExp
```

After some searching in the Scaladoc i found the package with the implicit conversion. Isn't there some automated way to do this search?

Edit: I'm not so good at formulating. My problem is to find out which package i have to import. The IDE already displays when an implicit conversion is used. But sometimes i believe that somewhere a implicit conversion should exist but have no clue in which package.

Comment: Sounds like a great tool for an IDE!

Comment: Or a search tool on the internet where you can enter the two types and which returns the possible packages.

Comment: Just as a supplemental: the alternative scala plugin [Google Summer of Code 2010 @ Scala IDE](http://www.scala-ide.org/2010/08/google-summer-of-code-2010/) for eclipse shows implicit conversions but only the (implicit) method name and not the package.

Comment: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/289036

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685479/find-all-implicits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetBeans plugin for Scala projects will allow you Ctrl-hover over a value to see any implicit conversions that have been applied. You can also use some of the compiler debugging options when attempting to compile your code; I think here -Xlog-implicits might be what you're looking for. More useful compiler flags can be found here: http://www.paulbutcher.com/2010/04/scala-compiler-advanced-options/